# MySQL group by with left join

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

I am trying to do a very complex query (at least extremely complex for me not for YOU :) )

I have users and comments table.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1f845/2

```
select user_id, status_id from comments where user_id in (2,3);
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | status_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       2 |        10 |
|       2 |        10 |
|       2 |        10 |
|       2 |         7 |
|       2 |         7 |
|       2 |        10 |
|       3 |         9 |
|       2 |         9 |
|       2 |         6 |
+---------+-----------+
```

If I use

```
select user_id, status_id from comments where user_id in (2,3)
```

It returns a lot of duplicate values.

What I want to get if possible.

If you see `status_id = 10` has `user_id= 2,3 and 4 and 2 multiple times.`
So from here I want to get maximum of latest `user_id` (unique) so for example,

it will be `user_id = 4 and 2` now the main complex part. I now want to get users information of `user_id= 4 and 2` in one column so that at the end I can get something like this

```
status_id |  userOneUserName | userTwoUserName
 10            sadek4             iamsadek2
 ---------------------------------------------
 7        |    iamsadek2     |      null
 ---------------------------------------------
 9 .      |    iamsadek2     |      sadek2
 ---------------------------------------------
 6        |    iamsadek2     |       null
```

How can I achieve such a complex things. 
Currently I have to do it using application logic.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. After running mysql --version I am getting 
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: There is no user 4 in this data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you literally want here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    status_id,
    (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM comments c2 WHERE c1.status_id = c2.status_id) user_1,
    (SELECT user_id FROM comments c2 WHERE c1.status_id = c2.status_id
     ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) user_2
FROM comments c1
WHERE user_id IN (2,3);
```

[image]

### Demo

 (your update Fiddle)

We can use correlated subqueries to find the max `user_id` and second-to-max `user_id` for each `status_id`, and then spin each of those out as two separate columns.  Using a `GROUP_CONCAT` approach might be preferable here, since it would also allow you to easily accommodate any numbers of users as a CSV list.

Also, if you were using MySQL 8+ or greater, then we could take advantage of the rank analytic functions, which would also be easier.

Comment: Simply awesome. But is there anyways that we can return user details from the users table instead of ids?

Comment: Yes, we can.  One approach would be to wrap my query as a subquery, and then join each of the two user columns (read: join twice) to some other table, to bring in another value based on the `user_id`.

Comment: If you can update your Fiddle with that other table, I could paste another demo link here.

Comment: "With that other table" did you mean the users table? Yes its there.

Comment: @sadek Have a look at [this updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1f845/52), which brings in the first and last names of each user, using the query I gave above as a starting point.

Comment: You got it. I am looking something like this but your last demo is skipping few results.. 6 is missing

Comment: @sadek Then use left joins to connect my query to the user table, [have a look here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1f845/53).  You may replace the `NULL` with some placeholder value, using `COALESCE`.  Or, you may leave it as is.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I found a problem. It returns same user. For example, it returns `user_id` for the status where only `user 2` has commented multiple times. How can I select the same id only once. Thank you

Comment: Please post a new Fiddle which has data showing the problem.  There may or may not be quick fix.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3269c/5 
You will see at the first row, user_1_id and user_2_id is same also this is same for third row. Thank you..

Comment: @sadek Using inner joins rather than left joins seems to fix it.  [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3269c/6) for your updated demo.

Comment: Thanks, but look at first row. It has user_1_id = 2 and also user_2_id = 2 also. It shouldn't return more duplicate entries

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question, or maybe adding bounty to this one.  Make sure that you show clear sample data and the exact output you expect.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will open a new question with the query you have given. will also let you know here in the comment. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
select status_id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(user_id) SEPARATOR ',')
from comments
group by status_id
```

Comment: Great, it shows the results but how can I get the user information from `2,7`. Is it possible?

Comment: Just add a WHERE user_id in (2,7)

Comment: Could you please show me an example? Thank you so much :)

Comment: select status_id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(user_id) SEPARATOR ',')
from comments
where user_id in (2,7)
group by status_id

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`, e.g. like so:

```
SELECT status_id, GROUP_CONCAT(userName) AS users, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.user_id) AS user_ids 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT status_id, user_id FROM comments WHERE user_id in (2,3)
) c
JOIN users u ON (c.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY status_id
ORDER BY status_id DESC
```

Comment: This answer is even more awesome. :) Could you refer me some study material for such advanced SQL learning? Thank you so much,

Comment: hard to say :) I like reading performance blogs on mysql, like the https://www.percona.com/blog/ and much of my knowledge actually comes from reading stack overflow and db stack exchange. Also the official resources are actually quite good, such as https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select/ or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Posted a question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799475/mysql-left-join-removing-duplicate-values-from-the-result . Please if you have time. Thank you